# VizFrame Column chart has 500m on its y-axis scale

Tags: javascript, sapui5

Hello I am using version 1.44.7 of SAPUI5, How do i remove the 500m scale on my column chart? I already added the min max for its scale yet the 500m is still there.

screenshot:
[500m on Y-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYR1z.png)

Here is the properties of the vizframe.

```
oVizFrame.setVizProperties({
            plotArea: {
                dataLabel: {
                   /* formatString:CustomerFormat.FIORI_LABEL_SHORTFORMAT_2,*/

                    visible: false
                }
            },
            yAxis: { 
                scale: { 
                    fixedRange: true, 
                    minValue: 0, 
                    maxValue: 1.5
                }
            },
            valueAxis: {

                title: {
                    visible: false
                }
            },
            categoryAxis: {
                title: {
                    visible: false
                }
            },
            title: {
                visible: false,
                text: 'Year'
            }
        });
```